# Does Cauchy-Schwarz work with higher powers, e.g. cubes instead of squares?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, problem-solving, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

A well-known version of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality for positive real numbers (the other one being [Titu's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Sedrakyan%27s_lemma_-_Positive_real_numbers)) is:

$$ \left( \sum_{i=1}^n u_i v_i \right)^2 \leq \left( \sum_{i=1}^n u_i^2 \right) \left( \sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2  \right).$$

I have seen a few generalisations of C-S including those [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Generalizations) but have not yet come across the following one:

$$ \left( \sum_{i=1}^n u_i v_i \right)^3 \leq \left( \sum_{i=1}^n u_i^3 \right) \left( \sum_{i=1}^n v_i^3  \right),\qquad (1)$$

where all the variables are positive real numbers. I can see that we can do:

$$ \left( \sum_{i=1}^n u_i v_i \right)^3 = \left( \sum_{i=1}^n u_i v_i \right)^2 \left( \sum_{i=1}^n u_i v_i \right) \overset{C-S}{\leq}  \left( \sum_{i=1}^n u_i^2 \right) \left( \sum_{i=1}^n v_i^2  \right) \left( \sum_{i=1}^n u_i v_i  \right),$$

but I do not see how to proceed from here.

So is this cubic version $(\ (1)\ )$ of C-S true, and how do you prove it? And further: is it true if we replace the $3$'s in inequality $\ (1)\ $ with an $\ k \geq 4,\ $ (i.e. the quartic, quintic etc version of $\ (1)\ )\ $ and how are these inequalities proven?

Comment: $n=2$, $u_i=1=v_i$ for all $i$: LHS = 8 whereas RHS = 4. The notation here is also confusing. $n$ is the number of summands, not the power with which you raise the sum.

Comment: @yurnero You're right - I shouldn't have used $n$ to describe the power. I changed this to $k.$

Comment: Jensen’s inequality

Comment: In the case $u_i = v_i = \frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}$, then $\sum_{i=1}^\infty u_i v_i$ diverges but $\sum_{i=1}^\infty u_i^3$ and $\sum_{i=1}^\infty v_i^3$ both converge.  So, for sufficiently large $n$ it must be the case that $\left(\sum_{i=1}^n u_i v_i \right)^3 > \left(\sum_{i=1}^n u_i^3 \right) \left(\sum_{i=1}^n v_i^3 \right)$.

Comment: @AdamRubinson: The generalization to CS that preserves dimension is  Hölder's inequality.

Comment: As already pointed out, this version (1) doesn't hold true.  However using a generalisation of Holder's inequality we can show $$ \left( \sum_{i=1}^n u_i v_i \right)^3 \leq n\cdot \left( \sum_{i=1}^n u_i^3 \right) \cdot\left( \sum_{i=1}^n v_i^3  \right) $$ As equality is possible here, this is tight.

Comment: @TedShifrin ah I've misread the question, my bad - I've deleted the comment.

Comment: @OliverDiaz thanks. I know my question is silly now that I see the answer. I'll have to look into Holder and Jensen's inequalities at some point because I haven't studied them before.

Comment: I am wondering now if $$ \left( \sum_{i=1}^n u_i v_i w_i\right)^3 \leq \left( \sum_{i=1}^n u_i^3 \right) \left( \sum_{i=1}^n v_i^3  \right) \left( \sum_{i=1}^n w_i^3  \right)\qquad ?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not true.
Let $u=(1,1)=v$.
Then

$$(\sum_i u_iv_i)^3=2^3$$
but $\sum_i u_i^3=\sum_iv_i^3=2$.